# Running "npm install --save X" in folder without package.json file

Tags: node.js, npm

I am writing a library and need to know what will happen if a user tries to run `npm install -S X` in their project before a `package.json` file exists.

I just tried this on Windows, and sure enough, NPM did not barf and went along with it's business but when the install command completed, there was still no `node_modules` folder nor a package.json file.

Does anyone know what is expected to happen? I assume I should require the users of my library to run "npm init" before running "npm install X" ?

Looks NPM does throw an error at the end of the install -

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'package.json'
```

but I wonder if that prevents the install process from create a node_modules dir, and actually putting the dependency in there.

Comment: Did you check on parent folders? I think it will install it in whichever parent folder contains a package.json (or node_modules folder, not sure of what it actually looks for)

Comment: yeah you're right, it installed it one directory above, but there is no package.json file there, so perhaps there was a node_modules dir there prior.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` without the `-g` flag will walk up the folder tree checking for folders that contain either a `package.json` or a `node_modules` folder.

If either of those conditions are met, then that folder will be treated as the current directory for the purpose of the `npm` commands you are running. If no such folder is found, then the current folder is used.

As you noted, a `node_modules` folder will be created and after the package is loaded into the cache it will be unpacked into that folder.